# How do I define a search string(keyword) in the text box?

Tags: android

I am trying to define a search string and new to android, not sure how to do the same. Any clue?
Here's my code for the same:

```
public final static String PROD_ENVIRONMENT = "https://mobile13.com/fwd/answers/answers/service/v1/?q=**KEYWORD**%20revenue&ui.theme=novadark&uuid=PADACT-002&userAgent=iphone";
```

I want to replace the KEYWORD with a dynamic string like %s, which can be recognized with a static string say "public static string KEYWORD" , which i can check ,in turn matches the typed keyword and display the results accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public final static String PROD_ENVIRONMENT = "https://mobile13.com/fwd/answers/answers/service/v1/?q="+KEYWORD+"%20revenue&ui.theme=novadark&uuid=PADACT-002&userAgent=iphone";
```

That is if you have the static variable in the same class. If you have it in a different class, say StaticUtils class then you can put it as `StaticUtils.KEYWORD`.

Comment: the issue is, in the search bar, i have to look for a keyword, such that, if the keyword is repeated twice, fragment 1 is displayed, else fragment 2 is displayed. and at the same time if fragment 1 is displayed i want to add the above link in the body of the fragment so that the keywords both match , how do i set such a condition for 2 keywords to match autosuggest and display  accordingly

Comment: Where are you storing the keywords that are entered for the first time?

Comment: got it, had to store the search keyword and display alongside like you mentioned in the code, +25 points for u

Comment: Glad you figured it out n happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

why will String.format not work?
[android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)